# convert datepicker format into input field

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I do have a form with a simple input field, using the jquery datepicker.

```
<input class="date" id="mydate" name="mydate" value="<?php echo $_GET['mydate']; ?>" />
```

When I send the form, the date format of my parameter have to be: **YYYY-MM-DD**.

```
www.mydomain.com/?mydate=2018-06-10
```

My javascript does look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydate").datepicker({
          format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
        })
```

Now, if I use the datepicker to select a date, the date format inside my input field is also **YYYY-MM-DD**. But for the vistor,the date format should look like this: **DD.MM.YYYY**.

Is there a way to convert the output of the date into another format? Thank you!

Comment: You can convert it on server side `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mydate))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `datepicker` provide `altField` option for this purpose:

```js
$("#displayDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  altField: "#mydate",
  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-UezNdLBLZaG/YoRcr48I68gr8pb5gyTBM+di5P8p6t8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input class="date" id="displayDate" value="20.12.2017" />
<input type="hidden" class="date" id="mydate" name="mydate" value="2017-12-20" />
```

Read [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was searching for. Works fine!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.